# Read csv file from S3 into spark in R

Tags: r, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I've below code to read csv from s3 into spark

```
test_data <- spark_read_csv(
  sc,
  name = "Invites",
  memory = FALSE,
  path = "s3://xxxx/customer/Sample.csv")


csvcharobj <- rawToChar(test_data)  
con <- textConnection(csvcharobj)  
data <- read.csv(file = con)
```

But code is failing with below error

```
> csvcharobj <- rawToChar(test_data)  
Error in rawToChar(test_data) : argument 'x' must be a raw vector
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the code as below and it did work

```
test_data <- spark_read_csv(
  sc,
  name = "Invites",
  memory = FALSE,
  path = "s3://xxxx/customer/Sample.csv")


test <- as.data.table(test_data)

cols_to_mask <- c("EmailAddress")

anonymize <- function(x, algo="crc32") {
  sapply(x, function(y) if(y == "" | is.na(y)) "" else digest(y, algo = algo))
}

setDT(test)

test[, (cols_to_mask) := lapply(.SD, anonymize), .SDcols = cols_to_mask]

print(test)
```